# send input through stdin in python subprocess.popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, stdin

I would like to start  nodejs through subprocess module and send input to it but facing below error...

code:

```
import subprocess
def popen(self):
    cmd = "node"
    args = "--version"
    spawn = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    (out,err)=spawn.communicate(args)
    print(out)
    print(err)
```

Result:

```
    [stdin]:1
--version
^

ReferenceError: version is not defined
    at [stdin]:1:1
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:132:18)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:309:38)
    at internal/process/execution.js:77:19
    at [stdin]-wrapper:6:22
    at evalScript (internal/process/execution.js:76:60)
    at internal/main/eval_stdin.js:29:5
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/process/execution.js:198:5)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1327:12)
```

Expected Result:

```
v14.14.0
```

basically, i want to start node and communicate with it, send input as and when required.

Popen is chose instead of run for better control over process and shell is set to true so OS variables are considered ex. $PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is equivalent to you starting `node`, then typing `--version` and pressing enter. This way, node will try to interpret it as a JavaScript statement, and it does not recognize the name `version`. Instead, you should pass it as a command line argument:

```py
subprocess.Popen(["node", "--version"], ...)
```

Comment: thanks for reply, could you suggest how i can send input trough ’communicate()’ ? ex. send a test.js file for execution...

Comment: i guess communicate() closes the stdout, stdin and stderr  once called...

Comment: @ElysMech Instead of `communicate`, you can use `spawn.stdout`, `stdin`, `stderr`, as regular streams.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use python oS package to run opearting system command
use os package popen method and read the output using read function

```py
import os

stream = os.popen('node --version')

output = stream.read()

print(output)
```